# Change MySQL 4.1 Windows to MySQL 4.1 Linux- Problem with the key Sensitive in query

Tags: mysql, linux

I need help to resolve this problem.

change the server MySQL 4.1 run on Windows to MySQL 4.1 run on Linux(debian).

This all working, but same query not return the correct data because key sensitive<\h1>.

In windows server i type:

> selete * from acao;

or

> Selete * from ACAO;

this two query return data.

But on Mysql 4.1 on linux is difference.

Is key sensitive<\h1>, 
if the table is difine on server "acao",

the query

> selete * from acao;

the query returns data, but if the query is:

> Selete * from ACAO;

I have more than 200 files with this query, so I do not have time to change all of this.

bests,
jgois

Comment: OMG it's 2004. I should buy some Apple shares.

Comment: it's true. hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a system variable that needs to be set in your my.cnf file.  You will need to add:
lower_case_table_names=1 in the [mysqld] section of your cnf file.

Kevin

Comment: Ty for help. Problem Solved